# How to Use Regular Expression Replace to convert object:method(...) to method(object,...)

Tags: regex, replace, lua

I have many source code lines in Lua (a script language) similar to

object:method(...)

Later I decide to make the method a general function, then I need to change the above lines to

method(object,...)

I think a regular expression replace can solve my problem, but I just struggled.

BTW, the name of object and method is following common identity convention, say consists of characters, numbers and "_" only.

Please help. It is better to use an text editor, such as Visual Studio, to do so.

Thank you in advance,

Ying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple search and replace:

```
\b(\w+):(\w+\s*)\(
```

And replace with `$2($1,` .

*Explanation*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word characters (in the replacement, this text is backreferenced with `$1`)
- `:` - a literal `:`
- `(\w+\s*)` - Group 2: 1 or more word characters followed with zero or more whitespace (in the replacement, this text is backreferenced with `$2`)
- `\(` - a literal `(` character

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA4rM6/2)

This expression will work in Notepad++ or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Lua solution:

```
S=[[
object1:method1()
object2:method2(a)
object3:method3(a,b)
]]

S=S:gsub("(%w+):(%w+)%(%)","%2:(%1)")
S=S:gsub("(%w+):(%w+)%((.-)%)","%2:(%1,%3)")
print(S)
```

Comment: It does not work if the argument list contains parentheses, but this is easily fixed by using `%b()` and a little post-processing.

Comment: `S=S:gsub("(%w+):(%w+)(%b())","%2(%1\0\0%3\0"):gsub('%z%z%(',','):gsub(',?%)%z',')')`